# React native target Samsung Galaxy S7

Tags: react-native, react-native-device-info

My styling is broken on Samsung Galaxy S7 - I am using [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info) is there a way I can target the Samsung S7 so I can conditionally set the styling?

When I try and use `DeviceInfo.getDeviceId()` and my emulator it gives me `Ùnknown`

```
import DeviceInfo from "react-native-device-info";
DeviceInfo.getDeviceId() //unknown
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code below you will get the get the name of the cellphone, in your case, Samsumg Galaxy S7:

```js
import DeviceInfo from "react-native-device-info";
DeviceInfo.getModel()
```

Please thumbs up if my answer is correct, waiting for your feedback :).